# How can I offset the validation error message on my radio buttons?

Tags: jquery

Question ive just add the required text to my radio buttons and yes it works, when I click submit down at the bottom it jumpts to the radio button and says please enter value which is fine sort of.

I need to offset it a bit because it goes behind the sticky header.

Ive not got any existing scroll JS code ive just added this but not sure why its not working :/

```
jQuery('#sageForm').submit(sageSubmit);

function sageSubmit() {
jQuery('#sageForm input[type=radio]').each(function() {
  var container = $('#sageForm'),scrollTo = $(this);

  if (scrollTo.is(':checked')) {
    var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - ($(window).width() / 2 - scrollTo.width() / 2) + container.scrollLeft();

    container.animate({
      scrollLeft: leftOffset
    }, 1000);
  }
});
}
```

Please see CodePen here - https://codepen.io/MrJoshFisher/pen/MQZLQR you may need to squash your window a little but ideally I want to offset it when the message appears is that possible?

Comment: I don't believe you can style the built in browser validation popups, and if you can it will probably be different for each browser, so you may be better off doing the validation yourself and showing your own custom errors.

Comment: how would I disable the default one just remove required?